# MACRO in LHS or RHS of == (!=) operator inside if() condition in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, operators, preprocessor

Here is my observation while I was analyzing a big code base. Here is the sample code

```
/*comparing received RAT(it may be 2G/3G/4G) Type from ip packet with numeric value */
if(pBearer.data.recv.rat_recv == 1)
{
        rrc.send_conn.rat_type = MY_GERAN; /* setting RAT as GERAN(enumerated value) i.e 2G */
        /* further processing of packet */
}
```

And this was the code reviewer comments

> As per coding standard, we should use MACRO instead of numeric value
>   as some time we may use `=` instead of `==`.

And it got resolved as

```
if(pBearer.data.recv.rat_recv == DB_RAT_GERAN) /* DB_RAT_GERAN is a macro defined somewhere in header file */
{
        rrc.send_conn.rat_type = MY_GERAN; /* setting RAT as GERAN i.e 2G */
        /* further processing of packet */
}
```

which is correct as sometime one may mistakenly use `=` instead of `==` like

```
if(pBearer.data.recv.rat_recv = 1) { /* always set RAT as 2G */ }
```

and compiler won't produce any warning(Good compiler, may be yes but hardly anyone analyze `make` or `build` result until it got crashed) or error about the same & it creates a problem.

Now here I got curios, one can use like

```
if(DB_RAT_GERAN == pBearer.data.recv.rat_recv)
```

rather than

```
if(pBearer.data.recv.rat_recv == DB_RAT_GERAN)
```

I prefer to use MACRO on **Left** hand side of comparison operator rather than Right hand side, as in worst case if mistakenly `=` is used in place of `==` like below

```
if(DB_RAT_GERAN = pBearer.data.recv.rat_recv){ }
```

compiler produces a very meaningful error like

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

but this

```
if(pBearer.data.recv.rat_recv = DB_RAT_GERAN) { }
```

simply get away.

Which of above two is advisable to use or even better technique & does anything `C` standard says about the same i.e MACRO should be used on LHS of comparison operator in checks or on RHS side ?

Comment: if the macro holds a variable, it doesn't help.

Comment: yes true @Jean-FrançoisFabre In my case macro `DB_RAT_GERAN` is a integer constant like `0x01`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether to use something like `if (a == 5)` or `if (5 == a)` is largely a matter of style.  The C standard doesn't say anything regarding the recommended usage of conditionals.

While the latter (often referred to as "Yoda Conditionals") does in fact guard against mistakenly using `=` instead of `==` (and is exactly what the code review comment you mentioned is talking about), however this style is not a easy to read.

Most compilers these days will emit a warning if you do the former.  In particular, gcc will warn against this if you use `-Wall` and MSVC will warn with `/W4`.  As long as you set your warning levels high enough (which you **always** should) and treat warnings as errors (`-Werror` for gcc, `/WX` for MSVC) so things like this don't get missed, I would recommend going with this style both for readability and for the tools that will catch this scenario.

Comment: and it's not always possible when both terms are variables for instance

Comment: Thanks for your valuable points. I agree with readability point of view.